# buffer.blockCopy error trying to fill objectlistview rows

Tags: c#, buffer, rows, objectlistview

I am trying to use Buffer.BlockCopy to copy a portion of an array (data.item) into another.  I get a compiler error about invalid stuff (see below)  if I try one thing, or a runtime error if I use a cast.   But it works fine if I just assign it: row[item.AspecName] = "random chars".   What am I wrong doing?

```
namespace ObjectListViewFramework
{
    public partial class ObjectListviewForm : Form
    {
        public DataTable ListRows { get; private set; }
  }

 }

    public void AddRows2(DLL_conduit data)
    {
        int columnIndex;
        int bufferIndex = 0;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < data.rowCount; rowIndex++)
        {
            DataRow row = ListRows.NewRow();
            columnIndex = 0;
            foreach (var item in objectListView1.AllColumns)
            {
                // this works dandy
               row[item.AspectName] = "random chars";

                // compiler error: the best overloaded method match has some invalid args
                 Buffer.BlockCopy(data.item, bufferIndex, row[item.AspectName], columnIndex * 256, 256);

                 // runtime error: invalid cast 
                 Buffer.BlockCopy(data.item, bufferIndex, (char[])row[item.AspectName], columnIndex * 256, 256);      

                ++columnIndex;
                bufferIndex += 256;
            }
            ListRows.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        objectListView1.AddObjects(ListRows.DefaultView);
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any difference whatsoever between your code allegedly causing a compile error and the runtime error.

Comment: @BenVoigt,  Sorry, cut/paste error. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Well, what data type is `row[item.AspectName]`?  Hiding the data type behind `var` definitely makes it harder to debug.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Good point. I edited now:               DataRow row = ListRows.NewRow();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially your row doesn't have any associated data.

`Buffer.BlockCopy` doesn't create an array to copy into.  You have to pass it an existing array, and you don't have one.

Your working code uses an indexed setter.  Your non-working code uses the indexed getter to retrieve the object currently in the `DataRow`.

Uses of `Buffer.BlockCopy` are few and far between.

Comment: Being new to C#, I don't understand.  I get it about Buffer.BlockCopy not creating an array, but not why row[...] not working.  Is it because there is no storage there?  If so, how would I rewrite to do so?  Would I have to "new" a string on every iteration (there are 9,000 rows with 5 columns each).

Comment: What format is your data in to begin with, is it UCS2 (the format used by `char[]`)?